# Search Analytics ViewsRecent & ViewsLifeTime is null

Tags: 2013, search, list-view

I'm trying to see the most viewed blog posts in a SharePoint farm. So I just query for:

```
https://sharepoint/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x0110*'
```

To get the `ViewsLifeTime` I have to include it as a sorting parameter. When I don't add a ViewsLifeTime sort, `ViewsLifeTime` is null. Is that the correct behavior?

```
https://sharepoint/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x0110*'&sortlist='ViewsLifeTime:Descending'
```

Now this works for blog posts in one Web Application, but blog posts on the MySite WA never have `ViewsLifeTime` or `ViewsRecent` populated - they are always `null`. I do know that the blog posts are [above the `TailTrimming` limit](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2014/01/23/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013/).

1. When are these View-Events generated? Like what is the flow? User opens blog post > Usage event > Seach crawl > I can see the view event? Is search the only thing that needs to run or is there some timer job?
2. Why do I get usage events in one web application, but not the other? Do I need to change timer jobs? Service associations? Web Application Features? Site Collection Features?
3. How to reliably get `ViewsLifeTime` and `ViewsRecent` for everything? Is it correct that I always need to include to `SortList` parameter otherwise the views properties are null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this has been quite a ride... Let me answer my own questions:

**Answer 1**: View events are generated "instantly", though you can't see them right away due to - you guessed it - timer jobs. Now let me explain the flow:

[image: Analytics processing flow]

> 1. Visitors do something on your website, for example, they view an item. This generates a usage event.
>
>    2. The usage event is recorded in the Event store.
>    3. The usage events are sent to the Analytics Processing Component where they are analyzed. The result is sent to the Search index.
>    4. When visitors navigate to a page that contains a Recommendations or Popular Items Web Part, a query is automatically issued and sent to
>         the search index.
>    5. The query results are returned from the search index and displayed in the Recommendations and Popular Items Web Part on your website.
>
> via [SharePoint IT Pro Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2014/01/14/an-introduction-to-recommendations-and-popular-items-in-sharepoint-server-2013)

**Answer 2**: My question was basically false. Blog post entries are tracked **nowhere** in SharePoint per default. Why? Blog posts are consumed via the `Post.aspx` page - this page is different than the URL of the list item (obviously). The problem is that the usage events are tracked based on the URL - since `Post.aspx?ID=1` is different than `DispForm.aspx?ID=1` the usage events are not correlated. You can't get blog post usage analytics be default 
The solution? I added a custom JavaScript to all `Post.aspx` pages that calls [`SP.Analytics.AnalyticsUsageEntry.logAnalyticsEvent2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spanalyticsusageentry.loganalyticsevent2?view=sharepoint-server) manually via JavaScript with the correct URL and pronto - I have usage events for blog posts.

**Answer 3**: I haven't a good answer for this. It seems like `SortList` always needs to include `ViewsRecent` or `ViewsLifeTime` otherwise you don't get usage statistics

A couple of links that explain everything in greater detail:

- [An introduction to recommendations and popular items in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2014/01/14/an-introduction-to-recommendations-and-popular-items-in-sharepoint-server-2013) [(2)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2014/01/17/modify-the-content-search-web-part-display-template-and-use-windows-powershell-to-start-usage-analytics-in-sharepoint-server-2013/) [(3)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2014/01/23/view-and-configure-usage-analytics-reports-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)
- [How to interpret SharePoint’s view count managed properties (like “ViewsLast1Days”)?](https://www.koskila.net/how-to-interpret-sharepoints-view-count-managed-properties-like-viewslast1days/)
- [Query SharePoint Search Analytics using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointtalk.net/2014/02/query-sharepoint-search-analytics-using.html)
- [Microsoft SharePoint Search Analytics In PowerShell – GetAnalyticsItemData](https://mpcomputers.de/microsoft-sharepoint-search-analytics-in-powershell-getanalyticsitemdata/)
- [How to get Search Analytics Reports programmatically in SharePoint 2013](https://radutut.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/how-to-get-search-analytics-reports-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2013)
- [[MS-SPASA] SharePoint Analytics Service Application Protocol](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-spasa/f6371eed-b598-4f71-8a61-6b10d8069fa4)

Comment: My counts are not updating in search query, My file have 3 views but search query shows 0, it's been days.

Can anyone give a pointer to correct documentation for this?